# Verificar número mayor a 50 millones

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito verificar si un número es mayor a 50.000.000, pero quiero evitar el típico:

```
if (numero > 50000000) {
   //....
}
```

> ¿Existe alguna manera de verificarlo con *regex", u otra manera?

Comment: ¿Porque evitarías la comparación?

Comment: solo quiero saber si hay alguna manera más "elegante" de hacerlo... es algo medio rebuscado, pero nunca esta de mas preguntar

Comment: por ejemplo `([5-9]\d{7})|\d{9,}`. Pero es como usar un destornillador para colgar un clavo

Comment: jajajajaj lo mismo pense xD!! @SJuan76

Comment: +1 @SJuan76 Te adelantaste por un segundo...

Comment: `numero  >  50 * 1000 * 1000 ` , el compilador lo optimizará a `numero > 50000000` pero hace más fácil su lectura

Comment: Esta pregunta está atrayendo respuestas basadas en opiniones. Me parece que deberías editarla para incluir un criterio como legibilidad, brevedad, preferentemente una que no haga obsoleta la respuesta aceptada y que tiene >+20 votos

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Para escribirlo más corto:

```
if (numero > 5e7) {
    //...
}
```

Eso es `5 * 10^7`
<sub>(o "*un 5 seguido de 7 ceros*")</sub>.

- Referencia: [Literales de Punto Flotante](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Literales_de_Punto_Flotante).

Y, [no, no, no, no, no, no!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChYFX.gif) No uses regex para algo tan sencillo como esto. Te va a hacer que una sentencia trivial se convierta en un elefante que intenta comer un maní a través del agujero de la cerradura... Para curiosos, el regex sería [`/^0*(?:(?:[6-9]|[1-5]\d|5(?=0*[1-9])))\d{7}/`](https://regex101.com/r/Nb2gsU/1), pero no lo usen, y mucho menos digan que yo lo escribí.

- > Y esto no es solamente por repetir lo que todo el mundo dice. Utilizando una expresión regular estarías haciéndolo ~150 veces más lento (varía para cada caso). En un código intensivo, iría sumando demoras, tomando 1 segundo más cada ~4e8 iteraciones.
  >
  > Comparar en: [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/numeros-vs-regex).

Comment: Muchaaaas gracias, pasando el tiempo marco como correcta :)

Comment: +1 de hecho esta es la mejor solución alternativa, "diferencia notacional"   para un mismo propósito. regex = cañon para moscas en este caso.

Comment: @NekoOs: Usar regex para comparar números es aún "peor" que responder en inglés a una pregunta en español :D

Comment: Simplemente elegante! No habia pensado que se pudiera solucionar asi +1

Comment: @IvanBotero Por supuesto, es notación científica; la mayoría de lenguajes la tiene. La notación e significa literalmente *x 10 ^ n*. En este caso, *50 x 10 ^ 7* lo que es igual a 50m.

Answer (score 7):

Como **aporte** a las respuestas de [Mariano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/84230/24137) y de [Larry U](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/85912/24137), agrego una posible solucion, obviamente no tan elegante.

```js
var X = 51000000;

if (X > (1000000 << 5) + (1000000 << 4) + (1000000 << 1)){
  console.log("X es mayor a 50 millones");
}
else{
  console.log("X es menor a 50 millones");
}
```

Usando [desplazamientos de bits](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_a_nivel_de_bits#Desplazamientos_de_bits), genero los siguientes numeros:

```
(1000000 << 5)  =  32000000
(1000000 << 4)  =  16000000
(1000000 << 1)  =   2000000
```

Los cuales al sumar dan como resultado `50000000`. Puede usarse para comparar y determinar si el numero es menor o mayor.

#### Actualizacion

He realizado una comparacion respecto a la velocidad con la que se podrian ejecutar dichas instrucciones, en relacion al comentario de @Ruben:

```js
var t0 = performance.now();

/* Codigo */

var X = 51000000;

if (X > (1000000 << 5) + (1000000 << 4) + (1000000 << 1)){
  console.log("X es mayor a 50 millones");
}
else{
  console.log("X es menor a 50 millones");
}

/* Fin Codigo*/

var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Tardo: " + (t1 - t0) + " milisegundos.");
```

```js
var t0 = performance.now();

/* Codigo */

var X = 51000000;

if (X > 5e7) {
  console.log("X es mayor a 50 millones");
} else {
  console.log("X es menor a 50 millones");
}

/* Fin Codigo*/

var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Tardo: " + (t1 - t0) + " milisegundos.");
```

Conclusion: La respuesta de Mariano, es mas eficiente, respecto a la velocidad en la ejecucion, como bien se puede apreciar en estos ejemplos.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna ventaja o situación en que es útil utilizar desplazamiento de bits para realizar una comparación de números?

Comment: Respecto a las ventajas o bien utilidades, no podria hacer referencia a ninguna, he hecho una pequeña actualizacion, mostrando el tiempo de ejecucion de ambos metodos, como tal el que ha usado Mariano, es en comparacion con el mio, mas rapido. Mas la pregunta del OP y lo escrito en los comentarios era respecto a otros metodos de llegar al mismo objetivo.

Comment: Gracias por responder y actualizar. Viendo las respuestas que está atrayendo esta pregunta ahora me parece basada en opiniones (muchas respuestas sin criterios claros para escoger una como la que mejor responde la pregunta)

Answer (score 5):

Se puede hacer la comparativa en binario, o en cualquier otra base.

Usando el método **`toString`**, pasándole como argumento un número base, es decir, **`toString(base)`**, podemos hacer la comparación del número en base 36, que es la máxima permitida por el método.

En este caso, si el string llega a tener una longitud igual a la del string **`tro8w`**, que es 50 millones en base 36, y además, que sea mayor alfabéticamente a ese string, o si tiene mayor longitud que la del string, nos tiene que devolver `true`.

```js
function es_mayor_a_50_millones(valor)
{
  var b36=valor.toString(36)
  return b36.length==5 && b36>"tro8w" || b36.length>5
}
var valores=[
  35 ,
  40000000 ,
  50000000 ,
  50000001 ,
  50000001000
]
for(var i in valores)
{
  var valor=valores[i]
  console.log( valor, es_mayor_a_50_millones(valor) )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Creo que usando regex, una cifra mayor a 50000000 se pueden representar de la siguiente forma:

- Si la cifra tiene 8 dígitos, el primero de ellos no puede ser igual a 50000000

  ```
    ^0*(?:5(?!0{7})\d{7}$
  ```
- Agregamos el resto de las cifras de 8 dígitos mayores que 50000000

  ```
    ^0*[6-9]\d{7}$
  ```
- Si la cifra tiene mas de 8 dígitos, el primero de ellos debe mayor o igual que 1 (evita validar 9 ceros o mas)

  ```
    ^0*[1-9]\d{8,}$
  ```
- Cualquiera de estas cifras puede tener ceros infinitos `0*` al inicio de las mismas.

#### Combinando estas expresiones nos queda:

[^0*(?:5(?!0{7})|[6-9]|[1-9]\d)\d{7,}$](https://regex101.com/r/ejRTeT/1)

`^` y `$` son para garantizar que la variable sea un numero

`(?:  )` Agrupa elementos sin guardar ninguna referencia o enlace para futuros usos.

`(?!  )` Me ayuda a detectar un patrón después de cierta expresión y descartarlo, en este caso 7 ceros después de un 5.

Comment: Una solución muy complicada para algo muy sencillo.

Answer (score 3):

Para los no tan "[científicos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notaci%C3%B3n_cient%C3%ADfica)":

```
function billones (n) {return n * 1e12};
function millones (n) {return n * 1e6};
function mil      (n) {return n * 1e3};
```

Y luego,

```
if (numero > millones(50)) {
   //....
}
```

O incluso,

```
var miNum = billones(9) + mil(millones(2)) + mil(321) + 654;
       // = 9,002,000,321,654;
```